# CMD start nor PSExec open interactive application in foreground when using PHP to connect to SSH

Tags: php, windows, cmd, openssh, psexec

I'm running the following through a remote PHP script that connects to SSH:

```
cmd /C start "" /MAX /b "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
```

The process does start however it remains in the background and will not open fully on the remote desktop. Is there any way to get it to work interactively (like how PSExec has the -i flag)?

Edit:

So the PHP connects to SSH with `ssh2_connect` then uses `ssh2_exec` in the following manner:

```
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, $shcom ))) {
```

where `$shcom` is the command passed to the SSH, such as:

```
    $shcom = 'cmd.exe /C start "" /MAX "%SystemRoot%\System32\calc.exe"';
```

I have previously used PSExec and PuTTY (note not via the PHP script) to manually open notepad.exe on a remote machine via the following:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\PSExec\" & psexec \\localhost -i 2 -ds "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
```

which did successfully work however this also does not properly function via PHP. At present neither CMD nor PSExec can bring up an interactive application in the foreground *automatically*.

Comment: Only the foreground window or a newly started program (2 secs) can put a window into the foreground. To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx for a full list of rules. PSExec copies itself to the target system using the admin share. Then connects to the target's Service Controller and installs itself as a service. Then starts the program. Windows has spent decades writing code preventing windows stealing focus.

Comment: There is no windows' feature to allow programs run remotely to interfere with an interactive user on the remote system.

Comment: For reference the final code snippet I posted does work to start a notepad process in the foreground, but ONLY if I send it manually via PuTTY. Do you know what the correct syntax would be for the PHP script to execute this?

Comment: You need to work out how to comply with the rules at that link.

Comment: I'm not sure you're reading into what I said; this does work using the snippet I already specified, just not automatically. I do not believe the process is executed at all via script but I can very much indeed run notepad using PSExec. The intention is to use it without human intervention.

Comment: You have to comply with the rules. It's that simple. You can't automatically mess with users.

Comment: Where would I be doing that? The PHP is authenticating into a SSH which is the same thing I do but instead of it being me it's a script.

Comment: It's designed to stop you doing what you are trying to do. So you need to comply, if possible, with that list of rules.

Comment: Why would it? I could just as easily run a batch file on my PC to execute that command and it would have the same automation effect. Again, that link lists nothing about using psexec via a script nor users, and I fail to see what difference it would make. Please suggest which of those rules the above does not adhere to.

Comment: Well you aren't the foreground window on the remote machine. Therefore programs you start aren't eligible to be in the foreground.

Comment: PuTTY is a terminal program. PuTTY connects to something. That something doesn't meet the eligibility criteria listed at the link. You need to make your something do one of the things on that list.

Comment: PuTTY works though... that is what I'm saying. With PuTTY it's fine and I can indeed get notepad to start.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window and run first `cmd /?` and second `start /?` and read both times the output help.

`cmd /C` starts a new Windows command process which is closed automatically because of `/C` when additionally applied command to execute in the command process terminated.

The command `start "" /MAX /B` starts one more command process with an empty string as window title and starting in this command process the GUI application *Windows Notepad* which should be started with a maximized window because of `/MAX` but which should run in background (= without visible window) because of `/b`.

So the mistake is using `/b` as really wanted is starting *Notepad* in foreground with maximized window instead of in background with no window.

And Windows must not be installed inevitably on drive C: in a directory named `Windows`. Therefore it is better to use one of those two commands:

```
cmd.exe /C start "" /MAX "%SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe"
cmd.exe /C start "" /MAX "%windir%\System32\notepad.exe"
```

The environment variable `windir` is an environment variable existing by default since Windows 95 with the path to the directory of running Windows.

The environment variable `SystemRoot` is an environment variable predefined by all Windows versions based on Windows NT with path to Windows directory.

Nowadays it is better to use `SystemRoot` as this environment variable is Windows built-in while `windir` is just predefined in the system environment variables list and therefore could be also removed.

See Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for a list of predefined environment variables with description.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Mofi! The process runs with the first example you provided however it's still apparently in the background.

Comment: Okay. With task better explained in question I understand now better what you try to achieve. Unfortunately I can't help further on this issue because of having no experience with usage of PHP to interactively run applications on a remote machine. I keep my answer as it at least explains one reason why the started application was not opened maximized in foreground on remote machine.